# How to make dokku run a predeploy script before running django's collectstatic?

Tags: dokku

Is it possible to make dokku run a predeplo script before django collectstatic? Using app.json and a predeploy script still runs after collectstatic.

I want to build docs using sphinx before collecting these as static files to be served.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the answer is to disable automated collectstatic by setting the env var DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1 and then adding collectstatic yourself to a pre-deploy hook, after whatever else you want.